# Is Cassandra jdbc still actively supported?

Tags: jdbc, cassandra

Looking through the Apache Cassandra page and other linked Cassandra documentation, emphasis seems to be on CQL and there are no references to JDBC.  Is a Cassandra JDBC driver still under active development?  A google search for 'cassandra jdbc' turns up a few things, but none appear connected to Apache or DataStax. If anyone is using a Cassandra JDBC driver, which one are you using?

Comment: Do you mean thrift? I haven't heard of JDBC for C*.

Comment: No, as I understand it, Thrift is no longer being developed.  I mean a "Java Database Connectivity" (jdbc) for Cassandra such as http://bigsql.org/cassandra/cassandra_jdbc.jsp

Comment: There is a Java driver provided by Datastax. Are you looking for that?

Comment: No, the DataStax driver does not implement jdbc.  It primarily provides a mechanism for submitting CQL commands from a java program, and getting the results back in a ResultSet.  Submitting commands as fully formed CQL strings is better than nothing, but it is inherently bug prone, since nothing gets checked by the compiler.  jdbc has methods for setting specific data types in query requests.

Comment: Could you figure out solution to the problem? Even I'm facing the same trouble. I need JDBC for latest versions of cassandra.

Comment: https://github.com/adejanovski/cassandra-jdbc-wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Digging around and I found one in [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/dbschema/cassandra-jdbc-driver) from the [DbSchema](https://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-jdbc-driver.html) people.
I've only tried a few basic queries so far, so this is more of a 'hey, look' rather than an endorsement.

Answer (score 0):

CData Software (the company I work for) makes a [JDBC Driver for Cassandra](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/cassandra/jdbc/). As of 31 May, 2016, the driver is in Beta, but it is written to the JDBC standard and should work in any and all environments that support JDBC.

The link above will take you to the page to read more about the driver and download a Beta (or trial/full version once the driver is released).